# Why is my function not being called after the DOM is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, responsive-design

Can someone explain to me why the `rescaleStuff` function below is not being invoked on the line where I attempt to invoke it after defining it?

```
jQuery(function ($) { // $(document).ready equivalent

    function scaleStuff()
    {
        // make elements with class 'same-height-as-width' have the self-explanatory property
        $('.same-height-as-width').each(function () {
            var thisElement = $(this);
            thisElement.height(thisElement.width());
        });

        // make font size of carousel proportional to height 
        var factor = 15; // factor to scale the font size, e.g. factor=15 means font-size of the outer div
                         // if 1/15 of its height. The descendant text elements have font-size defined in em
        $('#front-page-carousel-blue-strip').css('font-size', ($('#front-page-carousel-blue-strip').height() / factor).toString() + 'px');
    }

    scaleStuff(); // scale on page load

    // ... bunch of other stuff 

}
```

I shouldn't have to resize the window to get everything to scale immediately after I load the page.

Comment: because you call `scaleStuff` instead of `rescaleStuff`?

Comment: What gives you the indication that the function is not working? Are you receiving an error in the console? If not, have you added a break point inside the function to ensure it's getting invoked? Are the selectors correct and retrieving matched sets from jQuery?...

Comment: Why do you have the $ as a parameter to your function?  I think you want an `e` in there, or something else that represents the event object.  If what you're trying to do is encapsulate the `$` object, you want `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);` - but, that's an anonymous, self-executing function and doesn't wait for DOM ready either.  Inside that you can set up a DOM ready function, like the answers below.

Comment: Your implementation is fine. You've just got a syntax error. You're missing the closing `)` at the end of your document ready declaration. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951638/why-is-my-function-not-being-called-after-the-dom-is-ready/#answer-31951880

Answer (score 4):

I think you actually wanted:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ...
})
```

or

```
$(function() {
   ...
})
```

Note any combination interchanging `$` and `jQuery` is valid.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: Thanks for that, I edited my answer

Comment: @SeanKendle It actually will. Unlike in the linked question, the second implementation above is not a self invoking or self executing function. The second method is perfectly valid.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer.  Deleted my comment!  I didn't notice the starting $ at first.

Comment: The OP's implementation is correct. Their just missing the closing `)`. It should simply be a syntax error.

Comment: I actually have a paranthesis in my code. That was a type-o when I wrote here.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine. You're just missing the closing `)` after your declaration:

```
jQuery(function ($) { // $(document).ready equivalent

    function scaleStuff()
    {
        // make elements with class 'same-height-as-width' have the self-explanatory property
        $('.same-height-as-width').each(function () {
            var thisElement = $(this);
            thisElement.height(thisElement.width());
        });

        // make font size of carousel proportional to height 
        var factor = 15; // factor to scale the font size, e.g. factor=15 means font-size of the outer div
                         // if 1/15 of its height. The descendant text elements have font-size defined in em
        $('#front-page-carousel-blue-strip').css('font-size', ($('#front-page-carousel-blue-strip').height() / factor).toString() + 'px');
    }

    scaleStuff(); // scale on page load

    // ... bunch of other stuff 

}    /* <-- Missing the closing ")". */
```

Remember the `}` closes the function being passed as a parameter. The `)`  closes the `jQuery(...)` function invocation. Once you add it, it should work fine. I've mocked up an example below using your syntax to show that this indeed works:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  alert($().jquery);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: plus 1 for reflecting the exact OP issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) { ... });`

Comment: `jQuery(function($) { ... });` and `$(function () { ... });` are short hand methods for `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});

// Passing a named function instead of an anonymous function.

function readyFn( jQuery ) {
    // Code to run when the document is ready.
}

$( document ).ready( readyFn );
// or:
$( window ).load( readyFn );
```